# Can go combine XML child nodes without dedicated root element when unmarshling?

Tags: xml, go

I have an XML structure to work with were a part looks like

```
   <Rights>
      <Name>NAS</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>App</Name>
      <Access>1</Access>
   </Rights>
```

This is (obviously) a list, and it is guaranteed that it contains of pairs `Name, Access` (and always in that particular order). My question: Can I use the `encoding/xml` package's `Unmarshal` function to unmarshal `Name` and `Access` in a single struct?

Consider the following example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var XML = []string{`
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SessionInfo>
   <SID>abc123</SID>
   <Rights>
      <Name>NAS</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>App</Name>
      <Access>1</Access>
   </Rights>
</SessionInfo>
`,`
<SessionInfo>
   <SID>def456</SID>
   <Rights />
</SessionInfo>
`}

type Right struct {
    Name string
    Access int
}

type SessionInfo struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"SessionInfo"`
    SID       string
    Rights    []Right
}

func main() {
    for _,entry := range XML {
        info := SessionInfo{}
        if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(entry), &info); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Marshal failed", err.Error())
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", info)
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as expected:

```
// Only the first value is found
{SID:abc123 Rights:[{Name:App Access:1}]} 
// One (not existing) value was found and the struct's zero value was used
{SID:def456 Rights:[{Name: Access:0}]}
```

I could (and this works) define the properties independent of each other like

```
Names []string `xml:"Rights>Name"`
Accesses []int `xml:"Rights>Access"`
```

But I'd prefer the structure format of the first version without converting them manually.

Is there a way to get the expected result?

Comment: I would start by creating a custom []Right type, and then adding an UnmarshalXML method to the []Right type

Comment: Forgive me, but there are too many asumptions and implicit guarantees in this. Why not wrap each individual right in an according, anonymous `<right>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `XPath` library [xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery) not Go marshal/unmash method.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/antchfx/xmlquery"
)

func main() {
    s := `
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SessionInfo>
   <SID>abc123</SID>
   <Rights>
      <Name>NAS</Name>
      <Access>2</Access>
      <Name>App</Name>
      <Access>1</Access>
   </Rights>
</SessionInfo>
`
    doc, err := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, elem := range xmlquery.Find(doc, "//SessionInfo") {
        sid := xmlquery.FindOne(elem, "SID")
        fmt.Printf("sid: %s\n", sid.InnerText())
        for _, name := range xmlquery.Find(elem, "Rights/Name") {
            fmt.Printf("name: %s\n", name.InnerText())
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
sid: abc123
name: NAS
name: App
```